# Android: background of listview corners

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with rounded corners. How can I set the background of these corners? I need to set them grey, like main background but they are white.

[image]

My listview

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/cats_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#000"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            />
```

round_corners.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="17dp" android:topRightRadius="17dp"/> 

    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:endColor="#ff0000"
        android:startColor="#ff0000"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Comment: did you checked in device or emulator?

Comment: this snapshot is from emulator

Comment: emulator wont show the transform box. I belive that an graphical layout.

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand you

Comment: there is 3 blue dots @ top it wont show in emulator it will only show in graphical layout when selecting listview.

Comment: and...? this problem is on emulator too.. its just a snapshot

Comment: post your layout that you are inflating for a list item.

Comment: i try to set android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be possible to set the background of your xml shape to transparent?
You can use the system default

```
@android:color/transparent
```

Comment: there is no background attribute in shape

Comment: Ok. Can you try adding <solid android:color="#000000"/> in the first position. but instead of 000000 use your shade of grey?

Comment: thanks, solved, i have this listview in another layout, set in it bg tranparent, sorry, fool mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try followin **trick** of adding a view befor adding ListView.
That View have background color as gray.

```
<View
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/cats_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#000"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            />
```

I checked it, and it works.